# Migration from Google calendar v3 beta version to v3 1.8.1.820

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have migrate my asp.net application from Google calendar V2 to V3 Beta, But now they have released there new DLL having version 1.8.1.820, So can any one please help me in this regards how can I convert. In my V3 beta version I was using below code

```
 private CalendarService CreateService(string token)
{
    KeyValuePair<string, string> credentials = Common.Get3LOCredentials();
    var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
    provider.ClientIdentifier = credentials.Key;
    provider.ClientSecret = credentials.Value;
    var auth = new Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, (p) => GetAuthorization(provider, token, credentials.Key, credentials.Value));
    CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        Authenticator = auth,
        ApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIkey"].ToString(),
        GZipEnabled = false
    });
    provider = null;
    return service;
}
```

As in there new Version they don't have NativeApplicationClient class and so many functionality they don't have. So please provide me some documentation if any one is having, as Google didn't provide a good documentation for ASP.NET developers.

This is the code for new version of google calendar that i am using:-

```
private CalendarService CreateService(string token)
{
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = null;
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();       
    KeyValuePair<string, string> credentials = Common.Get3LOCredentials();
    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = credentials.Key, ClientSecret = credentials.Value }, new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar" }, "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Calendar.Sample.Store")).Result;
    var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Calendar API Sample",
    });
    return service;
}
```

Comment: Don't you love how each release has significant breaking changes from the last. Go Google!

Answer (score 0):

First of all the calendar API is not beta, and it's available here - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/.

The library was in beta in the last months and we work hard to improve it quality and remove the dependency in DotNetOpenAuth. Take a look in the announcements blog - http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/, all changes are explained there.

From release 1.8.1 we are not going to have any incompatible changes, because the library had reached GA (General Availability). All OAuth 2.0 documentation is available at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth. Take a look at this page, and let us know if anything is missing there. Specifically you can take a look in an [ASP.NET sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg/Tasks.ASP.NET.SimpleOAuth2) or in an [ASP.NET MVC code snippet](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this part but I am getting exception "one or more exception" Please check the question I have updated it, In above code I am getting CalendarService.Scope.Calendar as null, I am not sure why i am getting this as null and where i need to specify the accessToken that we got while first time authentication as I didn't see any where where we are specifing the token

Comment: I think the code mentioned on Google developer is for installed application but I am integrating in web application so need to specify the AccessToken in every request, so where can I specify AccessToken in request by using API. I did research over it but getting only old codes.